# can't add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE tblTransaction (
    strTransCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dtmTransDate datetime,
    strOwnCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strOwnName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strTransDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dblTransAmt double,
    strAcctCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strEntryCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (strEntryCode) REFERENCES tblEntry (strEntryCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (strAcctCode) REFERENCES tblAccount (strAcctCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (strTransCode)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
 CREATE TABLE tblVoucher (
    intVoucRefCode INT,
    strVoucRefDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   dtmVoucDate datetime,
   strOwnCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   strOwnVoucCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (strOwnVoucCode) REFERENCES tblTransaction(strOwnCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (intVoucRefCode)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

can't add foreign key constraint help
can't add foreign key constraint help
can't add foreign key constraint help
can't add foreign key constraint help

Answer (score 1):

To create a foreign key for `strOwnCode` from table `tblTransaction` you need to define `strOwnCode` as [`primary key`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)

```
CREATE TABLE tblTransaction (
    strTransCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dtmTransDate datetime,
    strOwnCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strOwnName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strTransDesc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dblTransAmt double,
    strAcctCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    strEntryCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (strOwnCode)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b086e)